# How can I decrypt binary data that ended with NUL characters in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption

Example:

```
$data = "Test Data\x00\x00";
echo strlen($data);

$key = "mykey";
$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MD5($key, true), $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
echo strlen($encrypted);

$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MD5($key, true), $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
echo strlen($decrypted);

$newData = rtrim($decrypted,"\x00");
echo strlen($newData);
```

Output:

```
11
16
16
9  <-- I want 11 here
```

So, is there any way to decrypt data that may already be null-padded before encryption, and get the correct length data back?

Comment: Sidenotes: 1) You shouldn't use ECB 2) You should use an IV 3) You should use authenticated encryption

Comment: This is interfacing with a third party, so I don't have control over what encryption to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because when encrypting, the data needs to be a certain size.  Your data is smaller than that, so it's being padded.  PHP pads data with NULL characters, so when you `rtrim`, you're removing *both* your NULLs and the ones added with PHP.

One solution is to pad the data to the correct length by using another method.  I personally use [PKCS7 padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#Byte_padding).

Here's an example of how to use this padding method (adapted from https://gist.github.com/1077723):

```
$data = "Test Data\x00\x00";

$key = "mykey";

$blocksize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

// PKCS7 Padding
$pad = $blocksize - (strlen($data) % $blocksize);
$data .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MD5($key, true), $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MD5($key, true), $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

// PKCS7 Padding
$strPad = ord($decrypted[strlen($decrypted)-1]);
$newData = substr($decrypted, 0, -$strPad);
```

DEMO: http://ideone.com/bMZxyf