# Common PHP mcrypt_encrypt() code sometimes fails decryption

Tags: php, encryption

This code is from several websites, the source of which has mentioned SO as a source for help in its creation.
This is the uncompressed version, of which I changed the base64 encode and decode to hex2bin and bin2hex as I thought this was giving me problems when passing between webpages, but was because I was on occations getting trash data as the decryption result.

With either code, using the same key and different data, on occasions gives me trash data as the decryption result. It seems to be the data itself, as opposed to repetition, the data size may be between 30 - 80 characters.

The data is just a series of numbers and letters, all within the usual ASCII standard, no nulls, nothing beyond standard email address characters.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, with PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 (Zend: 2.5.0)

Has anyone experienced this kind of problem?

EDIT: From reading more SO, apparently $iv should be the same for encrypt and at the time of decrypt, but if this is true why would it work most of the time anyway?

```
function mc_encrypt($encrypt, $mc_key) {
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $passcrypt = trim(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $mc_key, trim($encrypt), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    $encode = bin2hex($passcrypt);
    return $encode;
}

function mc_decrypt($decrypt, $mc_key) {
    $decoded = hex2bin($decrypt);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $mc_key, trim($decoded), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    return $decrypted;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rijndael is a symmetric block cipher. It operates on blocks and in this case, the blocks are 256-bit wide. The ciphertext is supposed to look random, but it isn't. Otherwise, it wouldn't be possible to reverse the encryption. Since this is ECB mode, there is no IV which randomizes the whole thing. And because of this every plaintext block combined with the key will result in the same ciphertext block. So the issue is reproducible only based on the same data.

Since the encryption is supposed to look random, it will happen that the first byte of the ciphertext will contain a whitespace (when shown as characters). `trim` removes 6 types of whitespace and will remove at least the first byte in those cases. So, the problem will happen in 6/256 of cases (~2%).

If for example the first byte is a space, then it will be removed. Now the first block doesn't have all the bytes and the block boundary for decryption is moved. So, the first byte from the next block is used as the last byte of the first block to decrypt the block. Since Rijndael is a block cipher, only garbage will come out. And this happens for all blocks.

**Usually `rtrim` is used instead of `trim` to unpad the plaintext:** `rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(...), '\0');`. The `trim` of the ciphertext should be removed completely.

This isn't whole story, because the end of the encryption/decryption is trimmed which can break the result. It's best to actually use [PKCS#7 padding by implementing it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26151135/1816580) and completely lose the `*trim`. Sadly php_mcrypt doesn't provide the PKCS#7/PKCS#5 padding.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - Are you saying, get rid of trim() and use the padding function in the link your provided before passing it to $passcrypt ?

Comment: I'm talking about the `trim`s in `$passcrypt = trim(mcrypt_encrypt(...` and `...$mc_key, trim($decoded), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB...`. And yes, I'd suggest not to use those `trim`s and use proper padding instead.

Comment: I tried the new padding in the link and removed trim, tested about 20 times with data based on the time. seemed fine, so I guess that's the answer - Thanks

Comment: You should test at least 500 times with random data to be relatively sure.